# Remove the special characters (like %20) from URL

Tags: uri

Is it possible to replace the URL encoded characters for space,?,etc. with the exact character ? Because one of the content in my site takes the following URL and it doesn't looks so nice!

> https://expatchoice.asia/eat-drink/restaurants-casual/ana-intercontinental-tokyo%E3%80%80ana%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%81%E3%83%8D%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BF%E3%83%AB%E3%83%9B%E3%83%86%E3%83%AB%E6%9D%B1%E4%BA%AC

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at [transliteration](https://www.drupal.org/project/transliteration) module. [Together with pathauto](http://polso.info/how-configure-pathauto-transliteration) you could get better urls. But i don't know how well this works with chinese characters.

Comment: Is this only for the file names and not the node titles?

Comment: It's for URLs. But you can get it to work with pathauto. So it depends on how you create the aliases for your nodes.